# Print Binary Tree - C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I am trying to print a Binary Tree in a more readable manner, instead of just in a line. I used the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484943/print-a-binary-tree-in-a-pretty-way) as a start, but that prints the data from left to right like this:

```
25
    15
        10
        20
    30
        35
```

I need it to look like this:

```
        25
    15       30
10    20        35
```

This is the code that I have:

```
void printTree(AVLNode* root, int indent)
{
    if (root != nullptr) {
        if (indent) {
            cout << setw(indent) << ' ';
        }
        cout << root->data << endl;
        if (root->left) printTree(root->left, indent + 4);
        if (root->right) printTree(root->right, indent + 4);
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get it to print the way I want?

Comment: Except for the missing slashes, your question seems pretty much the same as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674772/printing-out-a-binary-search-tree-with-slashes?rq=1). Is it close enough to be a duplicate?

Comment: from the 7th line of your code, write something like this:

    `   cout << root->data;`
    `    if (root->left) printTree(root->left, indent + 4);`
    `    if (root->right) printTree(root->right, indent + 4);
        cout<<endl;
    }
}`

Comment: Consider use of breadth-first traversal instead of depth-first traversal (that is implemented now)

Comment: @GovindParmar I referenced that in my question...I've already done the research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// .... your code ....

void buildTree(AVLNode* root, int scrWidth, int itemWidth)
// breadth-first traversal with depth limit based on screen width and output field width for one elemet
{
    bool notFinished = false;
    // check the root
    if (root)
    {
        notFinished = true;
    }
    // calculate maximum possible depth
    int depth = 1;
    int field = scrWidth;
    while (field > itemWidth)
    {
        depth++;
        field /= 2;
    }
    // check result
    if (depth < 1)
    {
        cout << " -= erroneous output options =-" << endl;
        return;
    }
    AVLNode** pItems = new AVLNode*[1];
    *pItems = root; // pointer to item on the first level
    int itemCnt = 1;
    int divWidth = 1;
    // loop for output not more than depth levels until the data is not finished
    // where level is current depth of tree, and root is on the first level
    for (int level = 1; level <= depth && notFinished; level++)
    {
        itemCnt = (level == 1) ? 1 : (itemCnt * 2);
        divWidth *= 2;
        // make list of pointers to refer items on next level
        AVLNode** list = new AVLNode*[itemCnt * 2];
        // output all utems of that level
        int nextCnt = 0;
        notFinished = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemCnt; i++, nextCnt += 2)
        {
            int curWidth = (scrWidth / divWidth) * ((i > 0) ? 2 : 1);
            cout << setw((curWidth>=itemWidth) ? curWidth:(itemWidth/(1+(i==0))));
            if (pItems[i])
            {
                cout << pItems[i]->data;
                list[nextCnt] = pItems[i]->left;
                list[nextCnt + 1] = pItems[i]->right;
                if (list[nextCnt] || list[nextCnt + 1])
                    notFinished = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << ".";
                list[nextCnt] = NULL;
                list[nextCnt + 1] = NULL;
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        // free the memory allocated for list of pointers
        if (pItems)
            delete[] pItems;
        pItems = list; // and shift to new one (for next level)
    }
    delete[] pItems;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // create some structure
    AVLNode * root = NULL;
    // code for making tree
    // ....
    buildTree(root, 80, 5);
    // some other code
    // ....
    return 0;
}
```

Call `buildTree(root, 80, 5);` prints the tree like (where `.` means NULL instead of item):

```
                                     64
                  58                                       .
        24                  62                   .                   .
   0        78         .         .         .         .         .         .
41   69    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
```

but `buildTree(root, 40, 10);` for the same data will output

```
               64
     58                   .
24        62         .         .
```

i.e. only three layers, because 4th level has 8 items and if each require 10 character total weight 40 is not enough.

Note: I have not enough time to debug the code and make it perfect, but I hope it will help you to find your own solution.